# How do I add a horizontal line in a html select control?

Tags: html

How do I add a horizontal line (`<hr>` tag) in the dropdown control or in select control in HTML?

Comment: why do you want to do this and how is this jquery related?

Comment: You can also use "optgroups" to kind of achieve a similar concept, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899148/html-select-option-separator

Answer (score 79):

Generally speaking this is not a feature of `<select>`, most browsers have very poor styling control for that control.  In Firefox you can do the following (though doesn't work in other browsers):

```
<select name="test">
    <option val="a">A</option>
    <option val="b" class="select-hr">B</option>
    <option val="c">C</option>
    <option val="d">D</option>
</select>
```

with CSS:

```
option.select-hr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; }
```

But generally speaking, the only method is to put an option in with dashes, and try to make it unselectable.

```
<select name="test">
    <option val="a">A</option>
    <option val="b">B</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">----</option>
    <option val="c">C</option>
    <option val="d">D</option>
</select>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/qM5BA/283/

Comment: The disabled seperator - Nice touch! But this might create issues when doing any operations using `selectedIndex`.

Comment: @VarunNatraaj: Yes, I've never found the need to use `selectedIndex` myself - but you would need to take account of elements with `.disabled` during any counts, calculations, movements of that index.

Comment: Seems even the firefox example doesn't work in firefox these days :)

Comment: The use of `optgroup` would allow you to avoid the issue with selectedIndex, as well as automatically being disabled.

Comment: @Chris-Jr Note the year, `optgroup` support wasn't as universal as it is now.

Answer (score 38):

I've run into this issue before and the only cross-browser way to achieve this is to use unicode box drawing horizontal characters. Browsers don't render spaces between these characters. Of course that also means that your page must accept unicode (utf-8) which is almost a given these days.

Here is a demo, this one using a "[light horizontal](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2500/index.htm)" box mark:

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled">─────────────────────────</option>
```

There are various unicode box character options you can use as separator which should be rendered without spaces between them:

"─", "━", "┄", "┅", "┈", "┉"

More about unicode box drawing characters here: http://www.duxburysystems.com/documentation/dbt11.2/miscellaneous/Special_Characters/Unicode_25xx.htm

You can also include them using HTML escape chars (copy and paste usually works by inserting the box characters' UTF-8 sequence, which browsers seem to respect, but if that's not an option), this for four light horizontal box marks in a row:

&#x2500;&#x2500;&#x2500;&#x2500;

which renders as

────

Comment: Great! Your variant of separator character is looking awesome in IE! Also i suggest to use optgroup label instead of option because you will be able change color of optgroup label, but not in disabled option (IE).

Answer (score 19):

The `select` element may only contain `optgroup` or `option` elements, and `option` elements may only contain text. Markup like `<hr>` is forbidden.

I would use an element like this to create a separator:

```
<option disabled role=separator>
```

You may consider markup like this:

```
<optgroup label="-------"></optgroup>
```

However, the rendering between different browsers varies a little too much to be acceptable.

Comment: When I was testing my answer, I tried the `<optgroup>` to see what it looked like these days, having written it off a few times in the past and it is still totally inconsistent; very annoying otherwise it would be a useful feature.

Comment: seperator role is a good one, glad to know there are alternatives!

Answer (score 12):

You could use the em dash "—". It has no visible spaces between each character.
In HTML:

```
<option value disabled>—————————————</option>
```

Or in XHTML:

```
<option value="" disabled="disabled">—————————————</option>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it was due to other css on the page, but I found that there are visible spaces between em dash in drop downs on Firefox and Chrome on OS X.
http://jsfiddle.net/PhZPh/

Comment: There's also the Unicode horizontal box character ("─").

Comment: You can also use its html escape char &mdash; (though copy and paste of that char seems to work as well)

Answer (score 9):

In the HTML Standard an `<hr>` is now allowed in the `<select>` element.

[HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-select-element)

Safari 17 was the first to support this.

[WebKit update](https://www.webkit.org/blog/14205/news-from-wwdc23-webkit-features-in-safari-17-beta/#and-more-html)

Chrome 119 was the first version of Chrome to support it as well.

[Chrome update](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/hr-in-select)

Firefox 122 came with support for this feature.

[Firefox update](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/122.0beta/releasenotes/)

```html
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <hr>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>
```

### Note

## EDIT: This solution is no longer needed for the major browsers, since they all support it now

[source](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_hr_hr_in_select)

Your browser will currently not display it correctly. Some browsers however support an `<hr>` that is added via script:

```js
const selectEl = document.querySelector('select');

selectEl.insertBefore(document.createElement('HR'), selectEl.childNodes[4]);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>
  <option>option 3</option>
  <option>option 4</option>
</select>
```

Both Safari and Chrome on MacOs render it correctly with the last snippet. Firefox however does not. (December 2023)

Answer (score 6):

```
<option>----------</option>
```

or

```
<option>__________</option>
```

but you can't write `<option><hr /></option>`

you could also add a css class to an empty `<option>` with a background image

```
<option class="divider"> </option>
```

Comment: +1 for using a background image. Good idea. But does it work? :)

Comment: I just tried adding a style attribute with both background colour and image, neither seem to work in Safari 7 sadly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I ran into a lot of posts in which no one even bother to find a elegant solution, although it is simple.
Everyone is trying do ADD something into between `<option>` tags, but no one thought about STYLING the `<option>` tag, which is the only way to do it and to look amazing.

To easy to be true ? Look

```
<select>
        <option>First option</option>
        <option>Second option</option>
        <option>Third option</option>
        <option style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(153,153,153,.3); margin:-10px 0 4px 0" disabled="disabled"></option>
        <option>Another option</option>
        <option style="border-bottom:1px solid rgba(153,153,153,.3); margin:-10px 0 4px 0" disabled="disabled"></option>
        <option>Something else</option>
    </select>
```

I've placed the style with the html for ease.

This doesn't work anymore, it's clear, don't know why people keep posting answers. The rules changed, this solution worked, I've been using it myself. 
Nowadays I'm using jQuery plugins for this.

Lates edit:
Everyone can use the amazing ***selectpicker*** plugin

[Dropdown plugin](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

Comment: It does, I'm using it. Maybe you should bring some arguments along the way.

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu?language=objc and try it for yourself in Safari 10.1

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome 66, Edge, Opera, anything mobile.  I've only ever seen this work in Firefox.  But I applaud your arrogance.  Bravo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a seperator of sorts into a  tag, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k4emic/4CfEp/

However, this isn't recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

I used JSP but you will see that is same.
I am iterating through a brandMap LinkedHashMap where if key >= 50000, then it is a line separator, else is a normal select option. (I need that in my project)

```
<c:forEach items="${brandMap}" var="entry">
   <c:if test="${entry.key ge 50000}">
     <option value=${entry.key} disabled>&ndash;&ndash;&ndash;&ndash;</option>
   </c:if>
   <c:if test="${entry.key lt 50000}">
     <option value=${entry.key}>${entry.value}</option>
   </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but Safari 17+ and Chrome 119+ now accept `<hr>` inside a `<select>` tag:

```
<select name="my-option">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <hr>
  <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  <hr>
  <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Read more here:

- [Select element: now with horizontal rules](https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/hr-in-select/)
- [WebKit Features in Safari 17.0](https://webkit.org/blog/14445/webkit-features-in-safari-17-0/)

Answer (score -5):

Simple Way :

```
<h2 style="
    font-family:Agency FB;
    color: #006666;
    table-layout:fixed;
    border-right:1px solid #006666;
    border-right-width:400px;
    border-left:1px solid #006666;
    border-left-width:400px;
    line-height:2px;"
align="center">&nbsp;Products&nbsp;</h2>
```

Comment: Don't see how this answers the problem.