# How To Separate Elements Using A Divider In A Dropdown Menu?

Tags: html, css

I want to separate certain elements in a  dropdown menu option, with a simple solid divider. Ideally I want to have the links 'Pinterest', 'Twitter', 'Bloglovin' and 'Instagram' to appear above this divider and the link 'Email' to appear below the divider. So essentially I'm separating the first half of links from the second half with a divider.

Below is the html coding to the dropdown menu:

```
<li><a href='#'>Social</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque.com'>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551'>Bloglovin</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque/blankesquexo'>Instagram</a></li>
<li><a href='mailto:blankesque@hotmail.com'>Email</a></li>

</ul></li>
```

The link to my site is as follows - http://www.blankesque.com.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Ummm...  he's trying to add a divider in a combobox, just like he stated??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a horizontal line in a html select control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317025/how-do-i-add-a-horizontal-line-in-a-html-select-control)

Comment: Why not add a <hr> between them as a seperator?

Comment: @JohnnyBones not a duplicate of that question at all. He is talking about an `<li>`, not a `<select>`

Comment: @JacobGray - I think you can use the same concept, though.

Comment: @JohnnyBones not really, `<select>`'s have a much more limited range of what can be styled with CSS. Both the answers below work in a `li`, but not in a `select`

Comment: @JohnnyBones They've told us what he's trying to do. They haven't told us what they tried, what's not working, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just target the last `<li>` in the social `<li>`(I added the class `.social` to it), with `:last-of-type` and add a border-top

```css
.social li:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<li class="social"><a href="#">Social</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque">Pinterest</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/itsblankesque.com">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.bloglovin.com/people/aladyinwhite-8315551">Bloglovin</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/blankesque/blankesquexo">Instagram</a></li>
    <li><a href="mailto:blankesque@hotmail.com">Email</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```