# Remove a dropdown value that has been selected from another dropdown menu but not using value attribute

Tags: jquery, html

[Remove a dropdown value that has been selected from another dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318361/remove-a-dropdown-value-that-has-been-selected-from-another-dropdown-menu)

same above question but not use any value attribute in the option tag

Comment: Why would your options not have value? That doesn’t make much sense to me.

Comment: because my list has so many options, so instead of using value attribute for each option I am using name attribute in the select tag

Comment: I think instead of capturing values we have to capture text which is selected??? ...help me

Comment: But without any values no matter what option you select the `select` element will have no value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put an `onclick` handler on each of the options.
2. Have the `onclick` handler get the html of the element e.g. `$(el).html()`
3. Loop thru the options of the other `select` menu.
4. Hide the one that has the same `.html()`