# How to make a divider in a select list dropdown asp.net core?

Tags: c#, dropdown, asp.net-core-2.0, selectlist

How can I make a divider between options in a select list? I've read it's possible to make a dummy object and then disable it? Is this the easiest way to do it and in case how can I do that?

Solution

```html
<select asp-for="GameId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Games, "Id", "Name"))" class="form-control">
     <option>Please select your game</option>
     <option disabled>──────────</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899148/html-select-option-separator

Comment: thanks I'm not sure how I wasn't able to find that link!

Comment: Specify `Group` property for your select list items and the select tag helper will group the tiems for you using `optgroup`. Refer [Select Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core MVC
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34624217/40521)